# Django Form tag and action attribute

Tags: django

I am not good at English, but no matter how much I try, there is a problem, so I write a question.
I wrote it using a translator, but I can read English a little bit.

I want login page in Django.
I have 2 app.
"mysite", "myapp"

mysite urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('myapp.urls')),
]
```

myapp urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from myapp import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_view

app_name = 'myapp'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('result', views.result),
    path('reuslt2', views.result2),
]
```

myapp views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'main_page.html')

def login_success(request):
    #login_info = [request.POST['username'], request.POST['password']]
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return HttpResponse('success')
        #return HttpResponse(login_info[0], login_info[1])
    else:
        return HttpResponse('fail')

def result(request):
    return render(request, 'main_page.html')

def result2(request):
    return render(request, 'temp.html')
```

The login page I want uses two input tags, and the method uses the POST method to get the ID and password input.

I connect 127.0.0.1:8000/result.
I can see 2 input tags.
click submit button. -> connect 127.0.0.1:8000/result2

If the above method is successful, I think it will be possible to communicate using the POST method between HTML configured in a different way.

If I access 127.0.0.1:8000/result, an error such as `Reverse for 'result2' not found. 'result2' is not valid view function or pattern name.` occurs.

I'm sorry that the sentence is not correct using a translator.

Creating an action attribute in the form tag as {%url 'result2'%} will cause an error unconditionally and will not be able to show the page.

Comment: Could you add the error message in the original language?

Comment: django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'result2' not found. 'result2' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

this is error in vscode...

Comment: Internal Server Error: /result/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LEEDONGSU\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 71, in reverse
    extra, resolver = resolver.namespace_dict[ns]
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^
KeyError: 'result2'


this..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `urls.py` you have a typo: it should probably be `result2` instead of `reuslt2`. I think if you fix this the reverse lookup should work correctly.

You also need to add the name to the paths of the urlpatterns (in `urls.py`):

```py
path('result/', views.result, name='result'), 
path('result2/', views.result2, name='result2')
```

Comment: I'm so sorry for the typo.

However, correcting the typo will result in the same error.

Comment: Do you have an html template you could show me?

Comment: this is test.html


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action = "{% url 'result2' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="user_1" id="user_1">
        <input type="text" name="user_2" id="user_2">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: this is temp.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    good
</body>
</html>

Comment: I'm very sorry, but I'm not used to using Stackoverflow, so I didn't realize that the comments were difficult to see.

Comment: test.html is very simple.. 1form tag and 2 input tags.
temp.html is just good message..

Comment: In test.html, if you change the form tag to this, do you get the same error?
<form method="post" action="{% url 'myapp:result2' %}">

Comment: I've found and used similar questions about namespace in the past.

I applied the code you provided and executed it.

However, the same error occurs.

Comment: Interested part is 127.0.0.1:8000/result2, and when approached directly, the message good is displayed.

It's too hard to move from 127.0.0.1:8000/result to result2 using the form tag.

Comment: This issue has been resolved.

The problem is urls.You did not add the name part in the path from py to urlpatterns.

Comment: path('result/', views.result, name='result'),
path('result2/', views.result2, name='result2')

I fixed the problem by modifying it with the corresponding code. You've been a great help. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'll edit my answer to include the solution so other people will not have to read through all the comments. Glad you found the problem! :)